# Learning React > Express > Node.js > Mysql database connection. Stuck with tutorial

Tags: mysql, node.js, reactjs, express

I'm in the process of learning React, and one of the steps is learning how to connect to a database using an Express server and a Mysql database. I was doing very well until I got stuck with a tutorial. As I've read many places in Stackoverflow, it seems it's a common thing that tutorial about all this assume a certain level by the learner. It's one of those cases.

Instead of wasting your time with parts of the problem that aren't really important, I'll just ask about the precise part where I'm stuck. The tutorial I'm following is the following:
https://www.edureka.co/blog/node-js-mysql-tutorial/

Everything was going smoothly until I came to the part where it says:
"Type in the below codes to define all the required routines:

learnerAddOrEdit"

First, you have to create the procedure:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `learnerAddOrEdit`(
IN _learner_id INT,
IN _learner_name VARCHAR(45),
IN _learner_email VARCHAR(45),
IN _course_Id INT
)
BEGIN
IF _learner_id = 0 THEN
INSERT INTO learnerdetails(learner_name,learner_email,course_Id)
VALUES (_learner_name,_learner_email,_course_Id);
SET _learner_id = last_insert_id();
ELSE
UPDATE learnerdetails
SET
learner_name = _learner_name,
learner_email = _learner_email,
course_Id = _course_Id
WHERE learner_id = _learner_id;
END IF;
SELECT _learner_id AS 'learner_id';
END
```

That went well, and it's created. Then, you have to add the code to Script.js:

```
//Router to INSERT/POST a learner's detail
app.post('/learners', (req, res) => {
let learner = req.body;
var sql = "SET @learner_id = ?;SET @learner_name = ?;SET @learner_email = ?;SET @course_Id = ?; 
CALL learnerAddOrEdit(@learner_id,@learner_name,@learner_email,@course_Id);";
mysqlConnection.query(sql, [learner.learner_id, learner.learner_name, learner.learner_email, learner.course_Id], (err, rows, fields) => {
if (!err)
rows.forEach(element => {
if(element.constructor == Array)
res.send('New Learner ID : '+ element[0].learner_id);
});
else
console.log(err);
})
});
```

That also went well. Then it asks you to POST the request in Postman (apologies, they only provide the picture here):

1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1S4Nb.png

That is where I get stuck. I proceed the same way the example image above shows, but I'm missing something. Here's what my request looks like:

[Picture of my request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QMDwx.png)

What am I missing? I see that the tutorial example somehow inserts "New Learner ID: 5328", but I have no clue where this is being done.

I apologize for this question, I'm obviously a noob at this and it's very hard to learn this connection to database part based on the tutorials I'm finding online. Your help is much appreciated :D Please let me know if I'm not explaining the problem well, I'll be glad to provide more information.

Best, Hugo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wont asume nothing first. let's take the easiest one first

1.- on your postman, instead of been text select "application/json" from the dropdown.

IF that did not make it.

2.- install body-parser

```
$ npm i body-parser
```

once that is done add it to your express

```js
const express =require("express");
const bodyParser=require("body-parser");

...


const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
```

first those two, but I am quite sure that all you need to do is to change the option on your postman from text to application/json

Comment: Thank you so much, your suggestion to change from "Text" to "JSON" unblocked the problem. Sorry for not posting the full Script.js file (it's the same as in the tutorial example), but I can confirm that body-parser was already installed and being required in Script.js so that was not the problem, it was the Text/JSON part that you mentioned. Now that this part is solved and working the Express server is showing me other errors in Terminal. I will work through those and hope I don't get stuck again. Thank you very much for the help!